# Play 1.2.4 is clearing my List when it gets passed to the template

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

I have a Controller with several pages that share a common error page.  The code for that error page looks like this:

```
@Util
private static void errorImp(PayPalPaymentStatus status, List<PayPalError> errors, boolean wasCharged) {
    if (wasCharged) {
        Email.chargedPayPalError(status, errors, wasCharged);
    }
    System.out.println("NumErrors=" + errors.size());

    renderTemplate("PayPal/error.html", status, errors, wasCharged);
}
```

and the `PayPal/error.html` looks like this:

```
<strong>NumErrors=</strong> ${errors.size()}
#{list _errors, as:'error'}
    <p><strong>Code:</strong> ${error.code}</p>
    <p><strong>Message:</strong> ${error.shortMsg}</p>
    <p><strong>Details:</strong> ${error.longMsg}</p>
#{/list}
```

When an error occurs and `errorImp()` gets called with a list of errors, I get NumErrors=1 at the console, but NumErrors=0 in the webpage.

Why is my list getting cleared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must change the name of your error list to : "errorList" for example because play send a error list object with each template : http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/templates#implicits